# c++ function return lambda not capturing string by value

Tags: c++, lambda

I am writing a lambda function builder that looks something like this:

```
std::function<...> Builder(const SomeObj& obj, const std::string& some_string) {
  return [&, some_string]() {
    cout << some_string;
  }
}

SomoeObj obj;
std::string some_string = "some_string";
Builder(obj, some_string)();  // => this will print an empty string instead of "some_string"
```

My question is:

1. why is it not capturing by copying and have a local string "some_string" to the lambda body itself?
2. how to make it work?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. This snippet has typos that are probably unrelated to your quesiton

Comment: [Works fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0d4ac510c129d65).  Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: It [works](https://godbolt.org/z/zmosMQ)

Comment: also works [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/y56n8wO3BzpE9n1c) ;)

Comment: 3 different online compilers, that cannot be wrong :)

Comment: @idclev463035818 fair enough. Didn't see the comment before posting :)

Comment: Btw, better to have `auto` return type (since C++14) to return lamdba directly.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not if you want to declare it in a header and define it elsewhere though

Comment: sorry guys, I was returning absl::FunctionRef<> instead of std::function in my actual code. That makes sense since I am returning a funciton ref which is a reference to the lambda, which has local scope to the Builder funciton

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the actual code that reproduce is returning a [absl::FunctionRef](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/functional/function_ref.h) instead of std::function. So it's returning a reference to a lambda that is local to the Builder function.

Switching the return type to std::function resolved the weird issue.